# bootstrap carousel is sliding on ios when clicking whitout controls

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've an issue I can't understand using the bootstrap carousel.
On mobile, I want to slide by swiping (and not clicking), and, on click, a pinterest button appears.
I've desactivated the carousel control buttons on mobile device (see css code below) and have a jquery rule to the pinterest button,
It works perfectly on android. But on ios, on click, the carousel is sliding.

Any idea ?

My code

```js
$('.carousel-item img').click(function() {
  $('.social-sharing').toggleClass('visible');
});
$("#carouselwork").on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {
  $('.social-sharing').removeClass('visible');
});
```

```css
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .social-sharing.visible {
    display: block;
  }
  .carousel-control {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="carouselwork" class="carousel slide work-single" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item  active">
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
      <div class="social-sharing ss-social-sharing">
        <a onclick="return ss_plugin_loadpopup_js(this);" rel="external nofollow" class="ss-button-pinterest" href="..." target="_blank"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="img-work-caract">
        <p>the title</p>
        <div class="counter">1/<span class="total">2</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." alt="..." />
      <div class="social-sharing ss-social-sharing">
        <a onclick="return ss_plugin_loadpopup_js(this);" rel="external nofollow" class="ss-button-pinterest" href="..." target="_blank"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="img-work-caract">
        <p>the title</p>
        <div class="counter">2/<span class="total">2</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev carousel-control" href="#carouselwork" role="button" data-slide="prev"></a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next carousel-control" href="#carouselwork" role="button" data-slide="next"></a>
</div>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it was a bug from the carousel bootstrap. 
A fix has been deployed on github, on branch v4-jo-fix-carousel-click-slide